# Revit svf vector and inventor svf vector are different from each other

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, revit-api, autodesk-inventor

I want to view revit and inventor files at the same time using autodesk forge. But one of the files is not standing straight.

to the revit file;

```
model.getUpVector()
```

output when i type

```
(3) [0, 0, 1]
```

to the inventor file;

```
model.getUpVector()
```

output when i type

```
(3) [0, 1, 0]
```

way it happens.
Is there a function where I can set the setUpVector while loading the models?

Comment: do you mean aggregated view in the viewer?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to batch see the revit and inventor files. however, the data of these 2 programs such as vectors and scales are different from each other. therefore vectors and their scales do not produce results properly.

Comment: Please add the image  in your question

Answer (score 0):

In [LoadModelOptions](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/reference/globals/TypeDefs/LoadModelOptions/) use placementTransform to change the scale and rotate the model 90' on the Y axis.

Please refer [this blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/loading-multiple-models-forge-viewer-v7)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already use it as you stated. But this may not be a healthy solution. For example, https://imgur.com/a/PxLP1ey, as seen in the picture, the door dimensions we drew in the inventor are correct, but not in the example we got from the inventor's own site. So we may need to write a separate "LoadModelOptions" for each inventor file. I want to make this more standardized. https://imgur.com/a/zUj6G0C I think the main reason for this problem is that the scales and vectors of inventor and revit do not fit together as seen in the picture.

Comment: yes, the scales between Revit and inventor files are different, we cannot standardize building and nut sizes.